# Python gRPC with MTLS : failed to connect to all addresses

Tags: python, openssl, grpc, mtls

I tried to test gRPC communication with mTLS, but the following error occurred.

**error message**

```
grpc._channel._MultiThreadedRendezvous: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
        details = "failed to connect to all addresses"
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1659422447.426000000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3151,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1659422447.426000000","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"src/core/lib/transport/error_utils.cc","file_line":165,"grpc_status":14}]}"
```

I run the server.py on my server, and then use the client.py to try to connect on localhost.

The following information may be useful:

- When I run the same client.py in the same network environment(just on the same server), I can connect to the server.py .
- I make sure that the server network environment is unblocked and the port(5060) is open to connetion.I even shut down the firewall.
- The gRPC without mTLS from localhost to my server is successful. Just this gRPC with mTLS failed.
- I unseted the http/https proxy.
- "sample.com" is the domain name of the server. I have added it to the hosts file.
- I run the same server.py on another server, and I can connect to it on localhost with the same client.py.So I guess there is something wrong with my server,but I don't konw what it is on details.
- I use "export GRPC_VERBOSITY=debug" "export GRPC_TRACE=all" to get more error message.

**The following is some potentially useful pieces of debug information I intercepted**

```
I0802 15:57:33.591844400     125 tcp_posix.cc:699]           READ 0x7f62cc018920 (peer=ipv4:[MYHOST]:5060) error={"created":"@1659427053.591576600","description":"Socket closed","fd":5,"file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_posix.cc","file_line":796,"grpc_status":14,"target_address":"ipv4:[MYHOST]:5060"}
D0802 15:57:33.592397300     125 security_handshaker.cc:181] Security handshake failed: {"created":"@1659427053.592378500","description":"Handshake read failed","file":"src/core/lib/security/transport/security_handshaker.cc","file_line":466,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1659427053.591576600","description":"Socket closed","fd":5,"file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_posix.cc","file_line":796,"grpc_status":14,"target_address":"ipv4:[MYHOST]:5060"}]}
I0802 15:57:33.593177800     125 handshaker.cc:93]           handshake_manager 0x7f62cc007510: error={"created":"@1659427053.592378500","description":"Handshake read failed","file":"src/core/lib/security/transport/security_handshaker.cc","file_line":466,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1659427053.591576600","description":"Socket closed","fd":5,"file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_posix.cc","file_line":796,"grpc_status":14,"target_address":"ipv4:[MYHOST]:5060"}]} shutdown=0 index=3, args={endpoint=(nil), args=(nil) {size=0: {}}, read_buffer=(nil) (length=0), exit_early=0}
I0802 15:57:33.593884200     125 handshaker.cc:126]          handshake_manager 0x7f62cc007510: handshaking complete -- scheduling on_handshake_done with error={"created":"@1659427053.592378500","description":"Handshake read failed","file":"src/core/lib/security/transport/security_handshaker.cc","file_line":466,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1659427053.591576600","description":"Socket closed","fd":5,"file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_posix.cc","file_line":796,"grpc_status":14,"target_address":"ipv4:[MYHOST]:5060"}]}
I0802 15:57:33.594520400     125 timer_generic.cc:447]       TIMER 0x7f62cc007578: CANCEL pending=true
I0802 15:57:33.595084000     125 subchannel.cc:956]          subchannel 0x7f62cc006c10 {address=ipv4:[MYHOST]:5060, args={grpc.client_channel_factory=0x12fd870, grpc.default_authority=sample.com:5060, 
grpc.http2_scheme=https, grpc.internal.channel_credentials=0x10cc3e0, grpc.internal.security_connector=0x7f62cc002230, grpc.internal.subchannel_pool=0x131c430, grpc.max_receive_message_length=536870912, grpc.primary_user_agent=grpc-python/1.47.0, grpc.resource_quota=0x12b9020, grpc.server_uri=dns:///sample.com:5060}}: connect failed ({"created":"@1659427053.592378500","description":"Handshake read failed","file":"src/core/lib/security/transport/security_handshaker.cc","file_line":466,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1659427053.591576600","description":"Socket closed","fd":5,"file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_posix.cc","file_line":796,"grpc_status":14,"target_address":"ipv4:[MYHOST]:5060"}]}), backing off for 847 ms
```

- The following is the source code of the client.py, server.py and the process of generating SSL certificate

**server.py**

```py
import time
from concurrent import futures
from helloworld_pb2 import *
from helloworld_pb2_grpc import *

_ONE_DAY_IN_SECONDS = 60 * 60 * 24

class Greeter(GreeterServicer):

    def SayHello(self, request, context):
        return HelloReply(message='Hello, %s!' % request.name)

def serve():
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
    add_GreeterServicer_to_server(Greeter(), server)

    with open('server.key', 'rb') as f:
        private_key = f.read()
    with open('server.crt', 'rb') as f:
        certificate_chain = f.read()
    with open('ca.crt', 'rb') as f:
        root_certificates = f.read()
    server_credentials = grpc.ssl_server_credentials(((private_key, certificate_chain),), root_certificates,True)
    server.add_secure_port('[::]:5060', server_credentials)
    server.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(_ONE_DAY_IN_SECONDS)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.stop(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    serve()
```

**client.py**

```py
from __future__ import print_function
from helloworld_pb2 import *
from helloworld_pb2_grpc import *

def run():
    with open('client.key', 'rb') as f:
        private_key = f.read()
    with open('client.crt', 'rb') as f:
        certificate_chain = f.read()
    with open('ca.crt', 'rb') as f:
        root_certificates = f.read()
    creds = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials(root_certificates, private_key, certificate_chain)
    channel = grpc.secure_channel('sample.com:5060', creds)
    stub = GreeterStub(channel)
    response = stub.SayHello(HelloRequest(name='world'))
    print("Greeter client received: " + response.message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

**Process of generating SSL certificate**

```bash
openssl genrsa -passout pass:1234 -des3 -out ca.key 4096

openssl req -passin pass:1234 -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.key -out ca.crt -subj  "/C=SP/ST=Italy/L=Ornavasso/O=Test/OU=Test/CN=Root CA"

openssl genrsa -passout pass:1234 -des3 -out server.key 4096
openssl genrsa -passout pass:1234 -des3 -out client.key 4096

openssl req -passin pass:1234 -new -key server.key -out server.csr -subj  "/C=SP/ST=Italy/L=Ornavasso/O=Test/OU=Server/CN=sample.com"
openssl req -passin pass:1234 -new -key client.key -out client.csr -subj  "/C=SP/ST=Italy/L=Ornavasso/O=Test/OU=Client/CN=localhost"

openssl x509 -req -passin pass:1234 -days 365 -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out server.crt
openssl x509 -req -passin pass:1234 -days 365 -in client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out client.crt


openssl rsa -passin pass:1234 -in server.key -out server.key
openssl rsa -passin pass:1234 -in client.key -out client.key
```

I have tried many ways but failed to solve the problem. I hope someone can provide a solution。

Thank you in advance!